# How to insert rows dynamically from a select query to another table in java?

Tags: java, sql, prepared-statement, resultset, batch-updates

I have a select query (using a prepared statement) which returns a Resultset. For example the query can be :

```
 SELECT * FROM TABLE;
```

and I want the result of this query to insert in another table, the select query is stored at database and will be usually a join query, so i don't know exactly the columns of the table, how its possible for each row of the Resultset to make an insert row in the form:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES ('THE VALUES FROM THE SELECTED ROW IN THE RESULTSET');
```

Comment: Have you come across the `SELECT INTO...` statement? If not, I suggest you research that.

Comment: Additionally there is the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` statement...

Comment: @adarshr it seems it does the job .. but in my case i don't have control on the select query, so i have to execute it as select and then insert or probably manipulate the select query and generate a select into query which does not seem simple.. is there any easier way?

Comment: How about the `INSERT INTO... SELECT` option suggested by others?

Comment: @adarshr yes i can use  `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`  .. Thanks for all

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can do both in one state ment:

```
insert into TableB (Col1, col2, col3, col4, etc..)
select Col1, col2, col3, col4, etc.. from Table A where Col5='condition'
```